# Is there any other way to sort numbers in ascending or descending order without using arrays?

Tags: c++, eclipse

```
int sortDigit(int number, bool order){

    if (order == ASCENDING && number>0) {
            for (int j = number; j>0; j/=10) {
                if (j%10==i) {
                    cout << i;
                }
            }
    }

    if (order == DESCENDING && number>0) {
            for (int j = number; j>0; j/=10) {
                if (j%10==i) {
                    cout << i;
                }
            }
    }

}
```

I am trying to arrange the numbers in arranging or descending order.

This code returns the sorted numbers, but due to no return value, the answer is followed by 32767:-
Ex:-

```
cout << "sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) = " << sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) << endl;
```

output:

```
 sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) = 1234532767
```

Could anyone please help me as what return value shall I use to solve this bug? or is there any better method to sort digits without using arrays?
Thanks a lot

Comment: please read about [mcve]. You are not showing the line that causes the error. Anyhow, you want `std::cout << sortDigit(....)` but `sortDigit` already does print the numbers. Simply call the function and dont try to pass its return value to `std::cout`

Comment: Can you explain why you want to avoid using arrays?    Your code, as it stands, avoids using an array, but needs to do significantly more calculations to achieve that.  Also, if you were to reverse digits and store the result in an `int`,  the result of reversing `100` would be the same as reversing `10000` - but your code produces different output.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `sortDigit` should return `void`, since there is nothing meaningful that it can tell its caller. And to call it, don't insert its (meaningless) result into `std::cout`. Just call it: `std::cout << "sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) = "; sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING); std::cout << '\n';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the value in a variable:

```
int sortDigit(int number, bool order){
    int ret = 0;
    if (order == ASCENDING && number>0) {
        for (int i = 1; i<=9; i++) {
            for (int j = number; j>0; j/=10) {
                if (j%10==i) {
                    ret = 10 * ret + i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (order == DESCENDING && number>0) {
        for (int i = 9; i>=0; i--) {
            for (int j = number; j>0; j/=10) {
                if (j%10==i) {
                    ret = 10 * ret + i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Or you could call the the function without `cout`:

```
cout << "sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING) = ";
sortDigit(54321, ASCENDING);
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpAppreciate it!!